# Linq group by with sub grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how to accomplish this with LINQ.  Haven't had too much experience with it.
I have the following information:
School, Test, Teacher, Student

I need to get a count of the number of schools and the number of teachers for each test, but I only need to count the instances where the teacher, for that test, has more than 10 students.

Here is the SQL:

```
select 
   test, 
   count(distinct school) school_count, 
   count(distinct teacher) teacher_count 
from 
  (select 
     test, 
     teacher, 
     school 
  from list 
  group by 
     test, 
     school, 
     teacher
  having 
     count(teacher) > 10) a 
group by a.test
```

My structure is very simple.  One class (not actual code)

```
class tests
{
public string teacher;
public string test;
public string school;
public string studentid;
}
```

Then I have a list of tests that I'm doing the querying on.
}

Comment: here is a tutorial that may help explain how to use the `Group By` Clause
[SQL Tutorial Group By](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-clause.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There is no distinction between `where` and `having` in Linq. You can do the following:

```
void Tests(IEnumerable<tests> tests)
{
    var result =
        from t in tests.Select(t => new {Teacher = t.teacher, Test = t.test, School = t.school}).Distinct()
        group t by t.Test
        into g
        where g.Select(t => t.Teacher).Distinct().Count() > 10
        select new
        {
            Test = g.Key,
            TeacherCount = g.Select(t => t.Teacher).Distinct().Count(),
            SchoolCount = g.Select(t => t.School).Distinct().Count()
        };

}
```

Side note: your database structure may require [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), your naming convention is not [recommended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I didn't add the structure I was working with..I've added it above.  Not quite the same as you assumed.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  Yeah, the stucture should be more normalized, but it's actually a csv file I'm reading, not a DB.  I've made a post below with something that is working but not too elegant looking

Answer (score 0):

```
    var initial_group = from st in this                            group st by new {  st.TestName, st.School, st.Teacher }
                            into testGroups
                            where testGroups.Count() > 10
                            select new
                            {
                                Test = testGroups.Key.TestName,
                                School = testGroups.Key.School,
                                Teacher = testGroups.Key.Teacher,
                                Items = testGroups
                            };

    var results = from grp in initial_group
                  group grp by grp.Test
                      into testGroups

                      select new
                          {
                              Test = testGroups.Key,
                              NumSchools = testGroups.Select(a => a.School).Distinct().Count(),
                              NumTeachers = testGroups.Select(a => a.Teacher).Distinct().Count()
                          };
```

This works, but it doesn't seem too elegant.  Would be nice to be able to combine the two queries.